Does Naomi Nagata go to her grave thinking that she killed her son?
In Babylon's Ashes - book 6 of the Expanse franchise - Naomi Nagata deliberately triggers an overload in the Ring Gate system, causing the warship Pella and its crew to be destroyed before it could rematerialize, when transiting from Earth (based on her  understanding of the mechanics involved in the disappearance of ships at that time in the franchise).
She believed that the Pella went down with all hands, including her son Filip Inaros.
Readers were made aware that Filip survived by jumping ship shortly before the Pella's destruction.
Did Naomi ever become aware of this, or did she go to her grave believing that she was responsible for his death?

At first I thought it was odd that Filip never reappeared in the later novels (I only became aware of The Sins of our Fathers upon reading Michael's answer, but later thought it was a nice touch: letting the reader know his decision without having everything come full circle in-universe.

There is no indication in the novels or novellas that she does so. The name Filip is not mentioned in Persepolis Rising or Tiamats Wrath. There is a single mention in Leviathan Falls, which implies that if she knew he was alive, she would have searched for him:

“If it were Filip,” she said, “I’d be going where he was.”

The novella The Sins of our Fathers has Filip as the viewpoint character. It includes him thinking back over 40 years which he has spent avoiding being recognised or linked to his past life, and there is no mention of any contact with Naomi despite him taking her last name.
